How to see the corresponding v8 implementation of a console command?
As I delve into the execution flow of the dev tool console to v8, I'm keen to understand which v8 function is being executed when we enter a line of code in the console panel.
I found the invoke_evaluate is making those interactions. However, the changes were not reflected once I made the changes to the evaluate function in v8 and recompiled the complete chromium.
So, some guidance on correctly identifying the corresponding v8 function and testing them on dev tools would unblock me on the first contribution.
TL;DR-
Where can I find the v8 function of
invoke_evaluate(params: Protocol.Runtime.EvaluateRequest)?

The Chrome DevTools function invoke_evaluate(params: Protocol.Runtime.EvaluateRequest) is indeed responsible for evaluating JavaScript code within the V8 engine. However, due to abstractions between DevTools, the Chromium browser, and the V8 engine, it is hard to exactly tell which V8 function does the evaluation.
Here's how you can further track down the corresponding V8 function:
Understand the flow:
One such function in DevTools is invoke_evaluate. This belongs to the communication between the DevTools frontend and the backend, which is responsible for the actual execution of JavaScript code.
The request typically goes through several layers until it hits the V8 engine where the code is evaluated.
Find the Bridge in Chromium:
The Runtime.Evaluate command in DevTools sends a message to the DevTools protocol handler in Chromium.
It then delegates this request to the relevant subset of the Chromium codebase, which interfaces with V8.
Concretely, you can look at Inspector- or Debugger-related files in third_party/blink/renderer/core/inspector because they contain glue code between DevTools and V8.
Then find V8 Evaluation Function. Trial evaluation of JavaScript code by V8 functions like v8::Context::Evaluate or v8::Script::Run.
The call to invoke_evaluate should eventually map down to one of these V8 functions after passing through the DevTools backend in Chromium. Testing Changes:
Once you've identified the correct V8 function, ensure that your changes are correctly compiled and linked into the Chromium build.
Either you need to clean up the cached builds or you have to be careful that your changes should be reflected by using a newly built binary. You could do this by doing a clean build, or you can use appropriate build flags to ensure that your changes get included.
Debugging Support:
You can instrument with logging or breakpoints in V8 functions you believe are processing the evaluate command. This may allow you to confirm that your changes are being executed.
There is a test infrastructure specific to the V8 itself, and you can write  a test exercising the Evaluate functionality; running this test will allow you to have confidence in your change before building all of Chromium.
Interesting starting points to investigate:
DevTools protocol implementation: chrome/browser/devtools/protocol
Blink Inspector/Debugger: third_party/blink/renderer/core/inspector
V8 Evaluation Logic: v8/src/api/api.cc, look for functions like v8::Script::Run

Amazing. It's a good kickstart. I can do further investigation from here. The bridge concept wasn't in my mind, misled me.
